# Xcode 4 Strip All symbols error when Archiving

Tags: iphone, xcode4

I have some static libraries in my Xcode 4 (iOS 4.3 SDK) project. When I archive the project i am getting the following error below when the tool attempts to strip symbols. I have the same settings i used for Xcode 3.2. I have noticed if i change the 'Strip Style' option in build settings from All Symbols to Debugging Symbols then the archive is built successfully.

```
Command /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/strip failed with exit code 1
```

As mentioned above I have not changed this setting from 3.2 so am wondering how to fix this issue?

Thanks

Comment: Did you find a resolution to this problem?

Answer (score 2):

I have met the question like this. I used three20 library in my project, when I archived it. "Strip Symbols Error" about the three20 libraries was produced.

I found the three20 library's "iOS Deployment Target" was "iOS 3.0", but xcode 4.6.3 has no iOS 3.0 sdk. I think it's a problem.

When I changed all three20 libraries' "iOS Deployment Target" to "iOS 5.1", these problems solved.

The fixed place is "Target"->"Build Settings"(All)->"Deployment"->"iOS Deployment".

Answer (score 1):

Please try the following steps. It may be robust for you.

1. open Terminal window.(find in spotlight
2. type same code:

   `sudo /Developer/Library/uninstall-devtools --mode=all`
3. hit enter,it will be ask for ur admin username/pass then press enter.
4. it will clean your previous directory.
5. after clean up,it will ask for something,type exit and close terminal.

---

Now, try installing your Xcode, if you get notification about iTunes (optional)

1. open activity indicator
2. find itunes helper process,select it,end process.

After installing new Xcode, restart mac and check.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to set to NO the build for active architecture only? Are you using in adhoc for your archive? Please try that to see what happens.